# Querying for a particular subclass(child) in an inheritance will render the base class(parent) attributes in addition to the subclass attributes

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm new to sqlalchemy-ORM and I don't know what to add to my code to make the child table sees the attributes of the parent table +its own attributes.

I'm creating a database using sqlalchemy-ORM .i did a join table inheritance between 'device' table (base class), 'hub' and 'controller' (subclasses). by default, the base class sees the attributes of its own and the subclasses but what if I want to do the other way around. my problem is the subclass in my code only sees its own attributes and I want it to see both the parent and its own attributes.

```
class Device(Base):
    __tablename__ = "device"
    id = Column('id' , Integer , primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name' , String)
    status = Column('status', Boolean)
    room_id = Column(Integer , ForeignKey('room.id'))
    type = Column('type' , String)

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'device', 'polymorphic_on': type
        }

class Hub(Device):
    __tablename__ = "hub"
    id = Column('id' ,Integer , ForeignKey('device.id'), primary_key=True)      
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'hub'
        }

class Controller(Device):
    __tablename__ = "controller"
    id = Column('id' , Integer , ForeignKey('device.id'), primary_key=True)     
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'controller'
        }
```

Comment: Just to be clear, are controller and hub specific types of devices, or do controllers and hubs connect different devices?

Comment: they're types of devices .

Comment: Ok.  Providing a possible solution below.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be trying to do is store most of the information on your Device object, then differentiate it by linking it to a record in separate tables called Hub and Controller.  For example, if you have 2 controllers and one hub:

```
===============================================
Table: "device"
id    name        status    room_id    type  
===============================================
1    Hub A         True          1     Hub  
2    Troller A     True          1     Troll 
3    Troller B     False         8     Troll 
===============================================

============
Table: "hub"
id  
============
1
============

===================
Table: "controller"
id 
===================
2
3
===================
```

While something like this might make sense in other cases, it doesn't take advantage of the relational database you're using.  Instead, I'd suggest just one table for *all* of your devices, then link them to a second table of device types:

```
class Device(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'device'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    status = Column(Boolean)
    room_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('room.id')
    type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('device_type.id')
    type = relationship('DeviceType', backref='devices')

class DeviceType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'device_type'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
```

Don't forget to `from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship`.  This way, you can select a type, then use the relationship to get all devices of that type.  You can also add a new type of device in the future without having to add an entirely new table.

In this case, the same tables from above would appear as such:

```
===============================================
Table: "device"
id    name        status    room_id    type_id  
===============================================
1    Hub A        True           1           1 
2    Troller A    True           1           2 
3    Troller B    False          8           3
===============================================

====================
Table: "device_type"
id    name
====================
1     Hub
2     Controller
====================
```

If you wanted to return a list of all controllers, simply query for the controller `device_type` and use the relationship/backref and get all associated devices:

```
controller_type = session.query(DeviceType).get(2)
controllers = controller_type.devices
```